# Reading a list from file, then writing in a loop to solve for math equation

Tags: python

I have a list in a file that is made up of numbers.

I have a command to read the number in the list:

But I am having error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Which I don't understand what 'int' is an issue.

```
with open('angles.txt', 'r') as f:
    print('Angle Sine         Cosine      Tangent')

    for number in f:
        degree= int(number)
        rad = math.radians(degree)
        sin = math.sin(rad)

        answer = degree[0]
        print(str(answer), end = '')

        print(format(math.sin(math.radians(rad)),'10.5f'),end='')
        print(format(math.cos(math.radians(rad)),'10.5f'),end='')
        print(format(math.tan(math.radians(rad)),'10.5f'),end='')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What line is your error is occuring on? Could you edit your question so that we can see an example of the data in your file?

Comment: "degree = int(number)" then "answer = degree[0]" is incorrect. Cannot index integer in python.

Comment: I apologize in advance, I am not good with editing code on here. but the error occurs on line 8 containing "rad=", saying "TypeError: a float is required". Rocky, I dont follow, am I suppose to have a line that reads and indexes the lines from the line first?

Comment: Can you add an example of angles.txt ?

Comment: sure  this is what is written in the file:
50
78
22
11
64
69
46
15
14
23

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your specific question about the `int` type error. The problem is that these two lines don't make sense to python:

```
degree = int(number)

answer = degree[0]
```

You're first defining `degree` to be an integer, and then trying to access that integer like a list! That doesn't work.

Comment: ok but is there a way to define the individual integers that are on the list instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat cleaned-up version (this assumes a single angle per line):

```
import math

print('Angle         Sine     Cosine    Tangent')
with open('angles.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        degrees = float(line)
        radians = math.radians(degrees)
        print(
            "{:5.1f}   {:10.5f} {:10.5f} {:10.5f}"
            .format(degrees, math.sin(radians), math.cos(radians), math.tan(radians))
        )
```

which produces something like:

```
Angle         Sine     Cosine    Tangent
  0.0      0.00000    1.00000    0.00000
 10.0      0.17365    0.98481    0.17633
 20.0      0.34202    0.93969    0.36397
 30.0      0.50000    0.86603    0.57735
 40.0      0.64279    0.76604    0.83910
 50.0      0.76604    0.64279    1.19175
 60.0      0.86603    0.50000    1.73205
 70.0      0.93969    0.34202    2.74748
 80.0      0.98481    0.17365    5.67128
```